# I want to make my imagemap responsive in a Vue project

Tags: vue.js, responsive, imagemap

I am working on a website using Vue.js and i need to implement a image where user can click on some specific part and it will show him information. I did some research and found about image map where it's possible to create a map with area. On each area, I will add a eventListener to show informations.

```
<img id="schema" style="width:100%;height:100%" src="../../assets/realisations/drahi.png"  alt="drahi" usemap="#image-map"/>  
<map name="image-map">
     <area target="" alt="network" title="network" href="#" v-on:click="change($event)" coords="190,718,292,665,215,312,190,302,168,314,88,673" shape="poly">
     <area target="" alt="batterie" title="batterie" href="#" v-on:click="change($event)" coords="581,356,599,381,634,392,666,394,704,386,727,369,734,360,734,209,724,188,704,177,680,171,644,171,618,178,593,188,581,209,581,238" shape="poly">
     <area target="" alt="pv" title="pv" href="#" v-on:click="change($event)" coords="756,297,846,378,1212,188,1123,107" shape="poly">
     <area target="" alt="load" title="load" href="#" v-on:click="change($event)" coords="545,791,577,804,659,764,657,675,593,644,545,669" shape="poly">
     <area target="" alt="car" title="car" href="#" v-on:click="change($event)" coords="568,1033,557,1027,544,1032,532,1026,523,1011,498,995,461,976,439,963,418,966,405,949,397,931,392,914,401,893,420,877,443,860,462,850,494,834,523,836,558,850,587,867,606,885,628,904,646,925,663,944,669,972,654,985,622,1007" shape="poly">
</map>
```

To make it responsive, i found some plugin like [image-map,](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-map) [image-map-resizer](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/image-map-resizer). But I fall on a error when I import it inside my component. This is how I import inside my E4CChart.vue :

```
<script>
   import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
   import { Chart } from 'highcharts-vue';
   import { ImageMap } from "image-map";
</script>
```

And this is the error :

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'image-map'.
> 'C:/Users/gerau/OneDrive/Bureau/Stage_LMD_DUT_Informatique/FRONTEND/front_end/node_modules/image-map/dist/image-map.js'
> implicitly has an 'any' type. Try `npm i --save-dev @types/image-map`
> if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'image-map';`Ve

tur(7016)

I did try the command `npm i ...` but it gave me a 404 error, nothing was found.

**So I ask you, do you know how to resolve my problem ?**

PS : this is the structure of the project

MyProject

- dist
- node_modules

  - ...
  - highcharts
  - highcharts-vue
  - image-map

    - dist

      - image-map.es.js
      - image-map.jquery.js
      - image-map.js
    - package.json
- public
- src

  - components

    - Realisations

      - E4CChart.vue
- .env
- babel.config.js
- package-lock.json
- package.json
- vue.config.js

Answer (score 0):

Since neither the `image-map` package itself nor the DefinitelyTyped project (`@types/*`) has provided a TypeScript declaration file for this package, you'll need to include one in your own project so that your TypeScript code can use it.

Fortunately, the package's API seems relatively simple. You can put the following into a new `src/image-map.d.ts` file:

```js
declare module "image-map" {
    export default function ImageMap(selector: string, debounce?: number): void;
}
```

(Technically that function returns a class instance that implements the functionality, but I don't think its members are intended to be public, and you probably won't need them for your purpose anyway.)

Comment: I did what you said but nothing changed. My project has only been created with `vue init webpack-simple appname` and i did install image-map after

Comment: @Tios Did you intend to create a TypeScript project instead of a plain JavaScript one? If you wanted plain JS, you may need to pass different settings to `vue init`. If you wanted TS, then there should be a `tsconfig.json` file in the top directory; please share that, as it might explain why the declarations aren't being seen.